# how to give read write permission to newly created folder using node.js

Tags: node.js, macos

I am creating a folder every time my code is executed in MAC but it is not having write permission to it due to which my code is failing once the folder is created

Answer (score 2):

You can set the permissions of the folder with `fs.chmod`:

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.chmod(pathToYourFolder, '755', function(err){
    if(err){
        //do soemthing with error
    }
});
```

Comment: do i need any package to use this ?

Comment: no, that's the `fs` module

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_chmod_path_mode_callback

Comment: I updated the example. Just require the module at the top of your file.